# How to Download a Blob Image from Python Azure Storage and create an Image object out of it?

Tags: python, image, azure, png, blob

I have a Block blob which is a png image. When I get the blob to bytes and try to create an image I get **not enough data**.
I am new to python and image analysis. The problem is Size of the blob is 1714562 and Width ad height if the image is 2024*1512 respectively. 
Below is the code which I retrive the image:

```
#Get Required image
def findImage(containerName, imageName): 
    return block_blob_service.get_blob_to_bytes(
            containerName, 
            input_folder + '/' + imageName, 
            max_connections=1).content;
```

And I have to do such a thing as described below to create an image:

```
 np.array(imageToProcess).reshape(imageSize)
```

Or

```
PIL.Image.frombytes('L', imageSize, np.byte(imageToProcess), 'raw', 'L', 0, 1)
```

- imageToProcess is the output of the findImage function.

I tried to get blob to stream or path still have the same issue. This Blob needs to be reshaped to actual image size and pass to another process function.
I will appreciate it if someone help me to undrestand the problem and possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PNG file you downloaded from Azure Blob Storage is a png-format binary byte string, you need to convert it to numpy array using OpenCV & Numpy or to `PIL.Image` object.

Here are my sample code using OpenCV & numpy or `PIL.Image`.

1. Using OpenCV & numpy

   ```
   import numpy as np
   import cv2

   data = findImage(containerName, imageName)
   print type(data)
   # <type 'str'>
   nparr = np.fromstring(data, np.uint8)
   # if the numpy version is 2.x
   img_np = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
   # if the numpy version is 3.x
   img_np = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
   print type(img_np)
   # <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
   ```
2. Using `PIL.Image` & `StringIO`

   ```
   from PIl import Image
   from StringIO import StringIO

   data = findImage(containerName, imageName)
   print type(data)
   # <type 'str'>
   img = Image.open(StringIO(data))
   print type(img)
   # <class 'PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile'>
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks alot for the Answer. I tried it but When I print the type of the data is not str is bytes. And now I get the error "cannot reshape array of size 9180864 into shape (2024,1512)" before it was array of size 1714562  which is the size of the blob and now this. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @sss PNG is a lossless compression image file format which need to be converted to a RGB pixel arrary via `cv2.imdecode` or just read it as a PIL Image object. So the blob size of PNG file is less than its real RGB pixel array size (=2024*1512*3), and you could not reshape a small array to a big array. I don't know why you get the blob content via method `get_blob_to_bytes` is `bytes` type, not `str`. If you can update more code details, I can try to help you fix it.

Comment: As I saw in the documentation the Blob content is str or bytes. But I don't know why I don't get the str one. I have nothing except my find image function and creating the image out of blob and convert it to numpy array doesn't work. I applied both of your suggestions. The thing is my Blob size is 1714562 and the img_np from your solutions return the size 9180864. Moreover the Image dimension is 2024*1512. so none of the array size is compatible to be reshaped to the actual image size.

Comment: I fixed the download of the blob by changing the `cv2.IMREAD_COLOR` to `cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB` However Now when  I want to upload the processed image back to storage gets the problem. I return numpy array back and have to upload the new image back to storage. My upload function  is `def uploadProcessedImage(containerName, imageName, image): 
    block_blob_service.create_blob_from_bytes(
    containerName,
    output_folder + '/' + imageName,
    image, 
    index= 0,
    max_connections =1,
    content_settings= ContentSettings(content_type='image/png'))`

Comment: And I pass the processed numpy array.tobytes() to my uploadProcessedImage function

Comment: My process function return numpy array of size 8928000 and when I perform tobytes() it returns 46894665. Further when I save it to storage the size of the blob is  71424000 and is a big file which does not have dimension and cannot be opened.